# How to debug embedded JavaScript in Safari

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

EDIT: Updated title to change 'inline' to 'embedded' to better reflect the nature of the question, per @dmi3y's suggestion.

In Chrome I commonly debug JS by setting breakpoints in my JS files, but Chrome also allows you to do this with the actual Document in the case that there's inline JS (i.e. JS that isn't in a separate .js file, but rather is in a `<script>` tag). I can't, for the life of me, find the same functionality in Safari. Does it exist, or am I out of luck?

Apologies if this question has already been asked...I checked the search and only found this (somewhat, but not really) related question: [How to debug lazily-loaded javascripts in Safari debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840117/how-to-debug-lazily-loaded-javascripts-in-safari-debugger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it (at least in 5.1.7 version for Windows), just go to the `Scripts` tab and select something like `http://yoursite.com/` it shows the similar picture as `Elements` do, but you obviously could debug embedded JS there.

PS: by the way around the terminology, I usually think about `inline` script for something like

```
<a ... onclick="myfunction();" />
```

or

```
<a ... href="javascript:myfunction();" />
```

that stuff might be used for `bookmarklets` or small calls.

code into `script` tag I use to call like `embedded`

it wold be interested if debugger could actually do work with inlined script?

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. My Scripts tab has an option called 'DOM Tree' or 'Source Code' (see this screenshot http://cl.ly/image/0S2S3t1F1a1Y) that was set to DOM Tree. When I changed it to Source Code, the line numbers (and ability to set breakpoints) appeared. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Mind if I edit to add that, or if you want to, I'll accept as soon as that's in there). Also, good point on terminology...fixing the title now.