# Iterating through JSON array not working as expected

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to iterate through the results of a JSON array sent via a php script in JQuery.  Currently all I want to do is print the length of the array, but that alone is not working so I think I am missing something here.

My current html/JQuery is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("./getFile.php?fileName=ni", function(json){
     alert("test");
     alert(json.length);
  });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Test script</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The JSON string coming across is:

```
[{"where":"up\n","time":"15:37:33"},{"where":"up\n","time":"15:39:34"},{"where":"up\n","time":"15:41:36"},{"where":"down\n","time":"15:43:37"}]
```

and this is produced by running a json_encode on a multidimensional array in php.

UPDATE:

I'm expecting the two alerts to be firing, but they are not.  Neither the test or the length of the array are showing up...

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php

$myFile = $_GET['filename'];

$file = fopen($myFile, "r");
$$response = "[ ";

$data = array();
$json = array();
while (!feof($file))
{
   $row = array();
   $currentLine = fgets($file);
   $parts = explode(" ", $currentLine);
   $length = sizeof($parts);
      $time = $parts[0];
      $where = $parts[$length-1];
   $json['where'] = $where;
   $json['time'] = $time;   
   $data[] = $json;
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: have you tried `for ( var i in json )`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json array". there' just json strings. You take that string and convert it to a native data structure, and you iterate THAT. The json string is purely a transport format

Comment: Define "not working." Do you get an error message?

Comment: Do you mean [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) ?

Comment: Is your php script returning anything? Check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: My php script is returning the string I wrote above:  [{"where":"up\n","time":"15:37:33"},{"where":"up\n","time":"15:39:34"},{"where":"up\n","time":"15:41:36"},{"where":"down\n","time":"15:43:37"}]

Comment: I tested that by calling the exact same URL listed in the JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the items using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each(items, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index +": " + value.where);
});
```

Comment: Or a for loop, it is just an array after all.

Comment: You aren't passing `$.each` anything to iterate over in the example.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, that would require ... not using jQuery! But still perfectly valid.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my example.

Comment: I figured .each would be the method, but why are my alerts not firing?  Is there something fundamentally wrong with my JSON object that is incorrect?

Comment: Set a break point in the `getJSON` callback and make sure that its getting there.

Comment: Set a break point?  Also, would an alert work just as well as console.log?  I'm using mountain lion and there appear to be issues with console.log

Comment: I'm going to guess your are using Safari. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714276/how-to-debug-embedded-javascript-in-safari

Comment: If I put an alert OUTSIDE of the getJSON block that will fire.  Is my getJSON not firing?

Comment: It sounds like it is not. But try debugging http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/13/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your json isn't an array! So it hasn't a length property. You have to change your data... This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e){

        // prevent default behaviour if needed
        e.preventDefault();

        $.getJSON("./getFile.php?fileName=ni", function(json){

            var arr = [];
            jQuery(json).each(function(index){            
                count = arr.push(this)
            });

            alert("test");
            alert(count);
        });

    });
});
```

@see http://jsfiddle.net/SA5G8/
​

Comment: that still is not firing any of the alerts. IS there something else I am missing?

Comment: Do you see it wrapped with `[]`<--these  .. then it is an array

Comment: The result of `jQuery.getJSON();` is actually not an array! It is parsed by the `jQuery.parseJSON();` method  which returns a JavaScript object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ This is why `alert(json.length);` does not work.

Comment: So maybe I need to construct my JSON differently?  I posted my php code.  I was wondering if the issue was there.

Comment: I copied your code bit for bit and I don't understand why it is not working :(  I see it works on jfiddle.  Why will it not work on my side?  I've tried both chrome and safari....

Comment: It seems there is an issue in your PHP. In your JS you're asking for `?fileName` but in your PHP it is `filename`. Otherwise you should  provide a url to your PHP which returns the correct json or even an example file. I need to test your stuff... If your PHP really returns the json as mentioned above it should work!